# For loop - validating input, program crashes (.hasNextInt())

Tags: java, validation, for-loop, input

I am writting a program in java that adds 5 numbers (positive integers) entered by the user using a for loop.
I have managed to make it work when the right input is given and even when negative integers are given, but the program crashes when a non int is entered.
Any help is appreciated!

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
        if (myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            x = myScanner.nextInt();
            if (x < 0) {
               System.out.println("Invalid input, enter again:"); 
               x = myScanner.nextInt();
            }
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, enter again:");
            x = myScanner.nextInt();// this works in the nested if but not here,  why?

        }
        sum += x;
    }

    System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
}//end class
```

Comment: What does it mean if hasNextInt returns false? If that happens, what do you think nextInt will do?

Comment: x = myScanner.nextInt();// this works in the nested if but not here,  why? Because there is no nextInt

Comment: What I think it happens is that .nextInt() uses the same input as before, in this case a non-int causing the program to crash. Am I right? If so how do I fix it? How can I make the scanner to ignore previous input and accept a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check whether the scanner has a next integer and then afterwards, still ask for an integer which it doesn't have...

Here's a corrected version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
    if (myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        x = myScanner.nextInt();
        if (x < 0) {
           System.out.println("Invalid input, enter again:"); 
        } else {
           sum += x;
        }
    } 
    else {
        // get whatever is on the scanner, since we know it isn't and int
        String crud  = s.next(); 
        System.out.println("Invalid input "+crud+" enter again:");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

InputMismatchException is being thrown, try this logic where the x = myScanner.nextInt is being called from one place,

```
int count = 0;
 while (true) 
 {
   try
   {
     if (myScanner.hasNextInt()) 
     {
       x = myScanner.nextInt();
       if (x < 0) 
       {
         System.out.println("Invalid input, enter again:"); 
       }
     } 
     else 
     {
        System.out.println("Invalid input, enter again:");
        continue;
     }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      System.out.println("Invalid input, enter again:"); 
      continue;
   }
   count++;
   sum += x;
   if(count==5)break;
 }
```